# Filter pyspark dataframe if contains a list of strings

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

Suppose that we have a pyspark dataframe that one of its columns (`column_a`) contains some string values, and also there is a list of strings (`list_a`).

Dataframe:

```
column_a      | count
some_string   |  10
another_one   |  20
third_string  |  30
```

list_a:

```
['string', 'third', ...]
```

I want to filter this dataframe and only keep the rows if column_a's value contains one of list_a's items.

This is the code that works to filter the `column_a` based on a single string:

```
df['column_a'].like('%string_value%')
```

But how can we get the same result for a list of strings? (Keep the rows that column_a's value is 'string', 'third', ...)

Comment: Are you looking for exact match or substring match? For the former, use `isin` for example: `df.where(df['column_a'].isin(list_a))`

Comment: @pault yes I know the `isin()`. I want to check if values contain the list's strings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IIUC, you want to return the rows in which `column_a` is "like" (in the SQL sense) any of the values in `list_a`.

One way is to use `functools.reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

list_a = ['string', 'third']

df1 = df.where(
    reduce(lambda a, b: a|b, (df['column_a'].like('%'+pat+"%") for pat in list_a))
)
df1.show()
#+------------+-----+
#|    column_a|count|
#+------------+-----+
#| some_string|   10|
#|third_string|   30|
#+------------+-----+
```

Essentially you loop over all of the possible strings in `list_a` to compare in `like` and "OR" the results. Here is the execution plan:

```
df1.explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*(1) Filter (Contains(column_a#0, string) || Contains(column_a#0, third))
#+- Scan ExistingRDD[column_a#0,count#1]
```

---

Another option is to use [`pyspark.sql.Column.rlike`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.rlike) instead of [`like`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.like).

```
df2 = df.where(
    df['column_a'].rlike("|".join(["(" + pat + ")" for pat in list_a]))
)

df2.show()
#+------------+-----+
#|    column_a|count|
#+------------+-----+
#| some_string|   10|
#|third_string|   30|
#+------------+-----+
```

Which has the corresponding execution plan:

```
df2.explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*(1) Filter (isnotnull(column_a#0) && column_a#0 RLIKE (string)|(third))
#+- Scan ExistingRDD[column_a#0,count#1]
```