# pyspark dataframe - issue of judging if a column contains multiple strings at the same time

Tags: pyspark

1.i have below pyspark dataframe

```
message,type,object
"they are one, two, three, four, five, six",typeA,objectA
"they are one, two",typeB,objectB
"they are four,five",typeC,objectC
"they are six, five, four, three, two, one",typeD,objectD
"they are six, one, five, three, two, four",typeE,objectE
```

2.Now i want to return a result that message column contains 6 words together: one, two, three, four, five and six. the relationship between 6 works are AND, not OR.

So the expected result is:

```
message,type,object
"they are one, two, three, four, five, six",typeA,objectA
"they are six, five, four, three, two, one",typeD,objectD
"they are six, one, five, three, two, four",typeE,objectE
```

3. Below is the code i used, but failed to return the expected result in 2.

   wordList = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]
   regex_pattern = "&".join(web_field)
   df.filter((df1.message.rlike(regex_pattern)))

I know that i can use 6 contains function to achive the expected result, but the code looks too long if there are many conditions.

```
df.message.contains("one") & df.message.contains("two")...&df.message.contains("six")
```

Could any expert please help take a look why the rlike function doesn't take me to expected result?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58186366/filter-pyspark-dataframe-if-contains-a-list-of-strings
Consider this answer,maybe try 

df1 = df.where(
    reduce(lambda a, b: a&b, (df['message'].like('%'+pat+"%") for word in wordList))
)

Comment: Give us your expected output sample df

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution for this.

write a regex expression to match if the columns contains all the required strings.

```
regex_pattern = "^(?=.*one)(?=.*two)(?=.*three)(?=.*four)(?=.*five)(?=.*six).*$"
df.filter(df.message.rlike(regex_pattern))
```