# Pyspark scan column against other column or list

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given the example dataframe:

```
+---+---------------+
| id|            log|
+---+---------------+
|  1|Test logX blk_A|
|  2|Test logV blk_B|
|  3|Test logF blk_D|
|  4|Test logD blk_F|
|  5|Test logB blk_K|
|  6|Test logY blk_A|
|  7|Test logE blk_C|
+---+---------------+
```

I'm trying to label it by comparing the log with a list (or df column, I can convert it easily) of the blocks tagges as anomalous.
This means that I need to scan each logLine against this list and add the label column.

Given the list:

```
anomalous_blocks = ['blk_A','blk_C','blk_D']
```

The expected resulting dataframe would be:

```
+---+---------------+-----+
| id|            log|Label|
+---+---------------+-----+
|  1|Test logX blk_A| True|
|  2|Test logV blk_B|False|
|  3|Test logF blk_D| True|
|  4|Test logD blk_F|False|
|  5|Test logB blk_K|False|
|  6|Test logY blk_A| True|
|  7|Test logE blk_C| True|
+---+---------------+-----+
```

I tried to think and look for a solution in SQL or Spark that could accomplish this, but came up short.
I thought of using a udf (user defined function) like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf 
def check_anomaly(text, anomalies):
  for a in anomalies:
    if a in text:
      return True
  return False

anomaly_matchUDF = udf(lambda x,y:check_anomaly(x,y))
```

But it takes way too long and doesn't seem the proper way to go about this.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
For clarity, the size of the list is way smaller compared to the number of rows/logs.
In other words, given N log lines and a list of M blocks tagged as anomalous

> N >> M

**EDIT2:**
Updated df to represent more accurately the real situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the `like` or `contains` operator and create a chain of condition using `reduce`.

```py
anomalous_blocks = ['blk_A','blk_C','blk_D']
label_condition = reduce(lambda a, b: a | b, 
                         [func.col('log').like('%'+k+'%') for k in anomalous_blocks]
                         )
# Column<'((log LIKE %blk_A% OR log LIKE %blk_C%) OR log LIKE %blk_D%)'>

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('label', label_condition). \
    show()

# +---+---------------+-----+
# | id|            log|label|
# +---+---------------+-----+
# |  1|Test logX blk_A| true|
# |  2|Test logV blk_B|false|
# |  3|Test logF blk_D| true|
# |  4|Test logD blk_F|false|
# |  5|Test logB blk_K|false|
# |  6|Test logY blk_A| true|
# |  7|Test logE blk_C| true|
# +---+---------------+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you. I was about to comment that I found a similar solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58186366/filter-pyspark-dataframe-if-contains-a-list-of-strings) but you beat me to it XD. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `isin` method on a `pyspark.sql.Column` to achieve this without needing UDFs (notice that I changed the contents of your `anomalous_blocks` list slightly to match exactly to the df's contents. This should be really cheap since you said `N >> M`):

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, "Test log blk_A"),
        (2, "Test log blk_B"),
        (3, "Test log blk_D"),
        (4, "Test log blk_F"),
        (5, "Test log blk_K"),
        (6, "Test log blk_A"),
        (7, "Test log blk_C")
    ],
    ["id", "log"]
)

anomalous_blocks = ['blk_A','blk_C','blk_D']

# Solution starts here
adapted_anomalous_blocks = ["Test log " + x for x in anomalous_blocks]
output = df.withColumn("Label", df.log.isin(adapted_anomalous_blocks))
output.show()

+---+--------------+-----+
| id|           log|Label|
+---+--------------+-----+
|  1|Test log blk_A| true|
|  2|Test log blk_B|false|
|  3|Test log blk_D| true|
|  4|Test log blk_F|false|
|  5|Test log blk_K|false|
|  6|Test log blk_A| true|
|  7|Test log blk_C| true|
+---+--------------+-----+
```

Comment: Thx for pointing out the function `isin`, I didn't know it existed. It doesn't really solve my problem though, because I need to check if the string contains the block, not to have an exact match. I tried your solution with the original blocks, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That's what I meant with adapting your small list. It is very easy to change that list in your example to have exact matches. Unless your reality is more complicated than the question you've written.

Comment: The list is small but compared to the dataset. I'm talking thousands against tens of millions or more

Comment: Ahhh so I see you've changed the data to be more representative of the real scenario. But there is already another answer that gives you what you want, so there you go :)